# dhcpd and bridge - No subnet declaration error

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, bridge, isc-dhcpd, subnets

I prepared dhcpd configuration in Debian 8 and it successfully worked but then I added bridge and dhcpd failed.

**bridge:**

```
root@remote:/home/s# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.00224dad5ddf   no      eth0
                                    eth1
root@remote:/home/s# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

iface ppp0 inet wvdial
provider orange

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

allow-hotplug br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

root@remote:/home/s#
```

**dhcpd:**

```
root@remote:/home/s# systemctl -l status isc-dhcp-server.service
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-07-01 21:51:43 CEST; 24min ago
  Process: 1037 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 01 21:51:41 remote dhcpd[1076]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Jul 01 21:51:41 remote dhcpd[1076]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Jul 01 21:51:41 remote dhcpd[1076]: you want, please write a subnet declaration
Jul 01 21:51:41 remote dhcpd[1076]: in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Jul 01 21:51:41 remote dhcpd[1076]: to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Jul 01 21:51:43 remote isc-dhcp-server[1037]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Jul 01 21:51:43 remote isc-dhcp-server[1037]: failed!
Jul 01 21:51:43 remote systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 01 21:51:43 remote systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Jul 01 21:51:43 remote systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.

root@remote:/home/s# cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf 
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.6;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
  option routers  192.168.0.1;}
root@remote:/home/s#
```

How to add this `"subnet declaration for eth0"` and fix dhcpd service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original DHCP server configuration used eth0. You've now replaced that in your network definitions with br0, so you need to update your DHCP server configuration accordingly.

Comment: Had to edit `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`